# How to get a split up a list of numbers and insert into another list

Tags: python, matrix

Currently I have a file with 6 rows of numbers and each row containing 9 numbers.  The point is to test each row of numbers in the file if it completes a magic square.  So for example, say a row of numbers from the file is 4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6.  The first three numbers need to be the first row in a matrix.  The next three numbers need to be the second row, and same for the third.
Therefore you would need to end up with a matrix of:
[['4','3','8'],['9','5','1'],['2','7','6']]

I need to test the matrix to see if it is a valid magic square (Rows add up to 15, columns add to 15, and diagonals add to 15).

My code is currently:

```
def readfile(fname):
    """Return a list of lines from the file"""
    f = open(fname, 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    lines = lines.split()
    f.close()
    return lines

def assignValues(lines):
    magicSquare = []
    rows = 3
    columns = 3
    for row in range(rows):
        magicSquare.append([0] * columns)
    for row in range(len(magicSquare)):
        for column in range(len(magicSquare[row])):
            magicSquare[row][column] = lines[column]
    return magicSquare

def main():
    lines = readfile(input_fname)
    matrix = assignValues(lines)
    print(matrix)
```

Whenever I run my code to test it, I'm getting:

```
[['4', '3', '8'], ['4', '3', '8'], ['4', '3', '8']]
```

So as you can see I am only getting the first 3 numbers into my matrix.
Finally, my question is how would I go by continuing my matrix with the following 6 numbers of the line of numbers?  I'm not sure if it is something I can do in my loop, or if I am splitting my lines wrong, or am I completely on the wrong track?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if each row in your input file contains magic square data you need to re-organize the code slightly. I've used a different technique to Francis to fill the matrix. It might be a bit harder to understand how `zip(*[iter(seq)] * size)` works, but it's a *very* useful pattern. Please let me know if you need an explanation for it.

My code uses a list of tuples for the matrix, rather than a list of lists, but tuples are more suitable here anyway, since the data in the matrix doesn't need to be modified. Also, I convert the input data from `str` into `int`, since you need to do arithmetic on the numbers to test if `matrix` is a magic square.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

def make_square(seq, size):
    return zip(*[iter(seq)] * size)


def main():
    fname = 'mydata'
    size = 3
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            nums = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
            matrix = make_square(nums, size)
            print matrix
            #Now call the function to test if the data in matrix 
            #really is a magic square.
            #test_square(matrix)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Here's a modified version of `make_square()` that returns a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, but please bear in mind that a list of tuples is actually better than a list of lists if you don't need the mutability that lists give you.

```
def make_square(seq, size):
    square = zip(*[iter(seq)] * size)
    return [list(t) for t in square]
```

I suppose I should mention that there's actually only one possible 3 x 3 magic square that uses all the numbers from 1 to 9, not counting rotations and reflections. But I guess there's no harm in doing a brute-force demonstration of that fact. :)

Also, I have Python code that I wrote years ago (when I was first learning Python) which generates magic squares of size n x n for odd n >= 5. Let me know if you'd like to see it.

---

## zip and iterator objects

Here's some code that briefly illustrates what the zip() and iter() functions do.

```
''' Fun with zip '''

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

#Using zip to create a list of tuples containing pairs of elements of numbers & letters 
print zip(numbers, letters)

#zip works on other iterable objects, including strings
print zip(range(1, 7), 'abcdef')

#zip can handle more than 2 iterables
print zip('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')

#zip can be used in a for loop to process two (or more) iterables simultaneously
for n, l in zip(numbers, letters):
    print n, l

#Using zip in a list comprehension to make a list of lists
print [[l, n] for n, l in zip(numbers, letters)]

#zip stops if one of the iterables runs out of elements
print [[n, l] for n, l in zip((1, 2), letters)]
print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((3, 4), letters)]

#Turning an iterable into an iterator object using the iter function
iletters = iter(letters)

#When we take some elements from an iterator object it remembers where it's up to
#so when we take more elements from it, it continues from where it left off.
print [[n, l] for n, l in zip((1, 2, 3), iletters)]
print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((4, 5), iletters)]

#This list will just contain a single tuple because there's only 1 element left in iletters
print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((6, 7), iletters)]

#Rebuild the iletters iterator object 
iletters = iter('abcdefghijkl')

#See what happens when we zip multiple copies of the same iterator object. 
print zip(iletters, iletters, iletters)

#It can be convenient to put multiple copies of an iterator object into a list
iletters = iter('abcdefghijkl')
gang = [iletters] * 3

#The gang consists of 3 references to the same iterator object 
print gang

#We can pass each iterator in the gang to zip as a separate argument 
#by using the "splat" syntax
print zip(*gang)

#A more compact way of doing the same thing: 
print zip(* [iter('abcdefghijkl')]*3)
```

Here's the same code running in the interactive interpreter so you can easily see the output of each statement.

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> 
>>> #Using zip to create a list of tuples containing pairs of elements of numbers & letters 
... print zip(numbers, letters)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')]
>>> 
>>> #zip works on other iterable objects, including strings
... print zip(range(1, 7), 'abcdef')
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')]
>>> 
>>> #zip can handle more than 2 iterables
... print zip('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
[('a', 'd', 'g', 'j'), ('b', 'e', 'h', 'k'), ('c', 'f', 'i', 'l')]
>>> 
>>> #zip can be used in a for loop to process two (or more) iterables simultaneously
... for n, l in zip(numbers, letters):
...     print n, l
... 
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
6 f
>>> #Using zip in a list comprehension to make a list of lists
... print [[l, n] for n, l in zip(numbers, letters)]
[['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6]]
>>> 
>>> #zip stops if one of the iterables runs out of elements
... print [[n, l] for n, l in zip((1, 2), letters)]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b']]
>>> print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((3, 4), letters)]
[(3, 'a'), (4, 'b')]
>>> 
>>> #Turning an iterable into an iterator object using using the iter function
... iletters = iter(letters)
>>> 
>>> #When we take some elements from an iterator object it remembers where it's up to
... #so when we take more elements from it, it continues from where it left off.
... print [[n, l] for n, l in zip((1, 2, 3), iletters)]
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
>>> print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((4, 5), iletters)]
[(4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
>>> 
>>> #This list will just contain a single tuple because there's only 1 element left in iletters
... print [(n, l) for n, l in zip((6, 7), iletters)]
[(6, 'f')]
>>> 
>>> #Rebuild the iletters iterator object 
... iletters = iter('abcdefghijkl')
>>> 
>>> #See what happens when we zip multiple copies of the same iterator object. 
... print zip(iletters, iletters, iletters)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'l')]
>>> 
>>> #It can be convenient to put multiple copies of an iterator object into a list
... iletters = iter('abcdefghijkl')
>>> gang = [iletters] * 3
>>> 
>>> #The gang consists of 3 references to the same iterator object 
... print gang
[<iterator object at 0xb737eb8c>, <iterator object at 0xb737eb8c>, <iterator object at 0xb737eb8c>]
>>> 
>>> #We can pass each iterator in the gang to zip as a separate argument 
... #by using the "splat" syntax
... print zip(*gang)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'l')]
>>> 
>>> #A more compact way of doing the same thing: 
... print zip(* [iter('abcdefghijkl')]*3)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'e', 'f'), ('g', 'h', 'i'), ('j', 'k', 'l')]
>>>
```

Comment: I actually need to use two-dimensional lists to solve it.  No tuples.

Comment: Why no tuples? They're actually more efficient than lists, and should be used when you don't need the mutability of lists. But it's pretty easy to convert a list of tuples to a list of lists; I'll add some code to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.  And I think I will take you up on that explanation for the making square function.  How does that return zip work?
Also why the if statement to call main?

Comment: I'll add a little zip & iterator object tutorial to my answer. As for the `if` statement to call `main()`, that's fairly standard Python practice. It's not really needed here, but it's a good habit to get into, as it makes it easier to turn your scripts into modules. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main for details.

Answer (score 0):

it only gets the first 3 column always because

```
magicSquare[row][column] = lines[column]
```

thus

```
def assignValues(lines):
    magicSquare = []
    rows = 3
    columns = 3
    for row in range(rows):
        magicSquare.append([0] * columns)
    for line in range((sizeof(lines)/9)) #since the input is already split this means that the size of 'lines' divided by 9 is equal to the number of rows of numbers
        for row in range(len(magicSquare)):
            for column in range(len(magicSquare[row])):
                magicSquare[row][column] = lines[(9*line)+(3*row)+column]
    return magicSquare
```

note that (3*row)+column will move to it 3 columns to the right every iteration
and that (9*line)+(3*row)+column will move to it 9 columns (a whole row) to the right every iteration

once you get this you are now ready to process in finding out for the magic square

```
def testMagicSquare(matrix):
    rows = 3
    columns = 3
    for a in len(matrix)
        test1 = 0
        test2 = 0
        test3 = 0
        for b in range(3)
            if(sum(matrix[a][b])==15) test1=1 #flag true if whole row is 15 but turns false if a row is not 15
            else test1=0

            if((matrix[a][0][b]+matrix[a][1][b]+matrix[a][2][b])==15) test2=1 #flag true if column is 15 but turns false if a column is not 15
            else test2=0

            if(((matrix[a][0][0]+matrix[a][1][1]+matrix[a][2][2])==15) and 
            ((matrix[a][0][2]+matrix[a][1][1]+matrix[a][2][0])==15)) test3=1 #flag true if diagonal  is 15 but turns false if diagonal is not 15
            else test3=0

        if(test1>0 and test2>0 and test3>0) println('line ' + a + ' is a magic square')
        else println('line ' + a + ' is not a magic square')
```

Comment: Ohhh okay I see.  Now how would I make my code test through each row from my file of numbers?

Comment: Your updated code is full of syntax errors due to large numbers of missing colons `:`

Comment: @PM2Ring then just help me fix it.. i was typing this on the go and not compiling on an IDE.. its just colons anyway