# Importing modules that have all its functions inside a main() function

Tags: python, program-entry-point

I read the answer given below:

[Why use def main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It seems it's better practice(?) to put all the code inside a `main()` function when creating modules to avoid executing it when imported.

But at the same time, when I put all my functions inside `main()` and I want to import it to another program, how would I call all these functions?

It seems counterproductive to do that but obviously I'm understanding it wrong, so I appreciate any help I could get.

EDIT: So let me know if I understood it, we don't put any actual functions inside main(), they are separate functions. The only thing that will go inside it its the `__main__` portion? For example:

Program `test.py`:

```
def my_function():
    print('Hello')

def my_function2(num):
    return num*num

print('Hi')
```

Modified `test.py`

```
def my_function():
    print('Hello')

def my_function2(num):
    return num*num

def main():    #so it doesn't execute when imported
    print('Hi')
```

Is this an accurate way of how you would use the `main()`?

Comment: You don't put all the functions inside `main`, you *call them from `main`*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`main()` typically *calls* your other functions but does not *contain* them. Your other functions will lie in the body of the script above `main()` and can be called in the standard way.

So your `test.py` example could look like this:

```
def my_function():
    print('Hello')

def my_function2(num):
    return num*num

def main():
    my_function()
    my_function2(5)

if __name__ == "__main__": # if module not imported
    main()
```

Comment: HI @Chris_Rands I updated the original post, please let me know if I understood what you said correctly.

Comment: @tadm123 You're not quite right yet, I've edited my answer to show your example. `main()` executes the other functions and the `if __name__ == "__main__":` executes `main()` when the module has not been imported

Answer (score 1):

You call the functions you want to execute within the block below. The functions are assumed to be already defined at the top of your module

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    call your functions you want to execute
```