# Workflow for creating packages in Go

Tags: go, package

I understand that programs in Go are run from the `main` function as their starting point. But I was wondering what the workflow is for creating functions for a new package.

In python for example I use `__main__` in module's when the module is called directly. When the module is imported from another file `__main__` would be ignored. Which is useful when you're developing a new module.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run module code here if module called directly
```

For Go I'm using a test.go file with a `package main` along with my main.go file to test functions in packages I'm creating.

```
// test.go
package main

import (
    "newpackage"
)

func main() {
    newpackage.MyNewFunc()
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or is this the standard workflow? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is: Please read https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages and https://golang.org/pkg/testing/

Comment: It looks weird to import main package from other packages. Can you provide some details to tell us why you have such a scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not trying to import the main package. I was just wondering if there was an equivalent to python's `if __name__ == "__main__":` which lets me try individual functions in a module without having to write a test file. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4041260/5319281

Comment: But as others have pointed out Go's testing tools seem the best way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't test in Go using `main`. Go has its own test framework.

First, read ["How to Write Go Code"](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) which will explain Go's package layout and testing tools. It's best to go with them because so much of the Go tools expect that layout.

When creating a package, put it somewhere in `~/go/src`. I'd recommend following the convention using the repository you like to use, even for things you aren't necessarily going to upload. It makes for better organization; `go get` will put other external packages in `~/go/src/` as well.

For example, I'd use `~/go/src/github.com/schwern/newpackage/` even though I don't intend to upload this to Github. `github.com/schwern` acts as my "organization" within the Go source tree.

Put the functions into `newpackage.go` under `package newpackage`.

```
$ cat ~/go/src/github.com/schwern/newpackage/newpackage.go 
package newpackage

func MyNewFunc() string {
    return "Hello!"
}
```

Then tests go in `newpackage_test.go` right next to `newpackage.go`. These should be familiar from Python, write a bunch of Test* functions. Unlike Python it doesn't use asserts.

```
$ cat ~/go/src/github.com/schwern/newpackage/newpackage_test.go 
package newpackage_test

import(
    "testing"
    "github.com/schwern/newpackage"
)

func TestMyNewFunc( t *testing.T ) {
    want := "Hello!"
    have := newpackage.MyNewFunc()

    if have != want {
        t.Errorf("MyNewFunc(): have: '%v', want: '%v'", have, want )
    }
}
```

If you run `go test` inside the package directory it will compile the current package and its dependencies, find and compile all `*_test.go` files in the package directory, and execute their `Test*` functions.

```
$ pwd
/Users/schwern/go/src/github.com/schwern/newpackage
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestMyNewFunc
--- PASS: TestMyNewFunc (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/schwern/newpackage   0.013s
```

Note that the test is in a different package than what its testing. That makes it a blackbox test, it can only see the exported (ie. UpperCase) functions. You can make a glassbox test by putting the tests in the same package, it's best to do that in a separate file like `newpackage_internal_test.go`.

Unfortunately Go doesn't come with assert functions, the above `if` and call to `t.Errorf` is the equivalent. Rather than constantly hand-roll them, there's libraries out there which provide assert functions like [stvp/assert](https://github.com/stvp/assert). After running `go get github.com/stvp/assert` you could write...

```
package newpackage_test

import(
    "testing"
    "github.com/schwern/newpackage"
    "github.com/stvp/assert"
)

func TestMyNewFunc( t *testing.T ) {
    assert.Equal( t, newpackage.MyNewFunc(), "Hello!" )
}
```

---

If you want an executable that uses `newpackage`, it should probably go in its own package. Unless it's an integral part of `newpackage`.

```
$ cat ~/go/src/github.com/schwern/newexec/main.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/schwern/newpackage"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(newpackage.MyNewFunc())
}
```

If you want to test `main`, [the `testing` package provides a special `TestMain` function](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main)... though I admit I do not fully understand it. Like any other language, it's best to put as much functionality as possible into library calls and have `main` be a thin wrapper.