# Conditionally execute program in Python

Tags: python

I only want to run my program if the user inputs 'ready'.

Is there a better way to nest the entire program under an if statement such as:

```
if input_variable == 'ready': 
     [program]
```

Is there something from the sys library that could help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: a `while` is probably better than `if` but you want something more *fancy* I guess..

Comment: `if not (input_variable == 'ready'): sys.exit()`

Comment: I'd avoid `sys.exit()` and use the current code you have. If you put `sys.exit()` inside your actual program, you could end up exiting in some nasty ways. I can't think of any _real_ reasons to back up what I'm saying, but I have strong feelings about it.

Comment: Are there any methods that does the opposite of sys.exit() i.e. something that starts the program instead of exiting?

Comment: @byxor What do you mean by nasty ways? The process running the script is killed, that's it.

Comment: while not input_variable == 'ready': pass
    [program]

Comment: They need to write the logic that decides whether or not to run `program`. I'm worried they'll mix it both inside and outside the program. There's no certainty that they'll do this, but `sys.exit()` gives me a bad feeling that they will. It's not an error with your suggestion, but it's a potential structural pitfall. Plus, I don't see why fully exiting is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_variable = ''
while input_variable != 'ready':
    input_variable = input()
[program]
```

With this you will keep asking for an input until the user types 'ready'

Answer (score 0):

Coldspeed made the comment that you could put this at the top of your file:

```
if input_variable != 'ready':
    sys.exit()
```

That will exit the program if it doesn't get the expected variable.  However, I personally prefer a different paradigm: put your program in a main function, and conditionally return:

```
def main(*argv):
  if input_variable != 'ready':
    return
  [program]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(*sys.argv)
```

There are [a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main) to put your program in a `main` function.  The most notable is that it allows you to import the file without actually executing it, which can be very useful for debugging.