# Python. Program within another program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to run a program within another program using the import feature.  It runs, however, it bypasses my function and just runs the other program.

```
import ex35
def beginning():
    print "you have three door choices.  door a,b,c"
    door=raw_input("> ")
    if door=="c":
        ex35.start(door)
    elif door=="a":
        print "do i have to put stuff down?"
    else:
        print "i finally got it to work"

beginning()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   # stuff only to run when not called via 'import' here
   main()
```

Comment: what's in ex35?

Comment: If you have code that will be run normally in `ex35` put that into a `if __name__ == "__main__":` loop as when you import a python file it runs as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it) post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523791/why-is-python-running-my-module-when-i-import-it-and-how-do-i-stop-it)

Comment: the program ex35 has three options.  in other words the game i am making is huge.  it starts off asking about three doors (one of which leads to ex35) and in ex 35 it askes the user for three more choices.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: the if name loop doesnt work.  which i dont understand why.

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041238/why-use-def-main and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Answer (score 0):

okay i figured it out.  kinda sorta of . the whole if_name_==*"main*: didnt work so i came up with this

def start():
    print "you have three door choices.  door a,b,c"
    door=raw_input("> ")

## if the user puts c then it should run ex 35 function start

```
if door=="c":
     import ex35
elif door=="a":
    import ex1
else:
    import ex2
```

start()